# Javascript animated background not covering whole screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used javascript to **create an animated background** to my website **https://coolio85.com**

**This is my HTML Code where the color shifting is meant to take place**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to coolio85.com</title>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/anibackground.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gradient" />
```

**This is the css to position the background to fit the full page**

```
#gradient {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

**This is the java script code to use the DIV Id**

```
$('#gradient').css({
    background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
```

There is a black bar from the solid background color that the background is originally set at the top of the screen.

Comment: Hi. Did you try to set the height of the body to 100vh ?

Comment: as a side note you cannot animate linear-gradient like this

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry i'm new to this. What do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean that linear gradient cannot be animated by changing color .. so if you expect an animation, it won't happen

Comment: ok i see your issue ... it's not with the animation, and i has nothing to do with gradient also

Comment: it's the margin of h1 collapsing with body ... use `h1{margin:0}`

Comment: Thank you so much that worked @TemaniAfif

Answer (score -1):

As I said in a comment, you can do something like that :

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#gradient {
  height: 100%;
}
```